# Ajax refuses to send data in very strange circumstances

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

I have a form, in which I need to send data selected via AJAX to. The whole idea is once the form data has been selected, an ajax call sent via `jQuery.get()` calls another function which receives and decodes the data in PHP and uses that data as an id to get more data from a database. The data from the database is then re-encoded and sent to a javascript function which prints more data, based on what was passed.

My problem is that, anytime I reference either `$_GET` or `$_POST` using `<?php ?>` tags in a javascript function, I get an error telling me that my javascript functions are undefined. I know that this is working *partially*, at least, because the AJAX call does get sent when I remove the `$_GET/$_POST` superglobal.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();        

function printSubCategories(categories) {

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

        var opt = document.createElement('option');

        opt.text = categories[i]['name'];
        opt.value = categories[i]['id'];

        jQuery('#subcategories').append(opt);
    }    
}

function recieveAndPrint() {
<?php
    $categories = getCategories(json_decode($_GET['parent']));
?>
    printSubCategories(<?=json_encode($categories)?>);
}

function ajaxCategories(pathToFile, ajaxData) {  
    jQuery.get(pathToFile, {'parent' : ajaxData}, function(ajaxData) {
        //alert('Data loaded: ' + ajaxData + <?=json_encode($_POST)?>);
    });

    recieveAndPrint();

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that a javascript compilation error is not occurring in your dynamically output functions. This would certainly cause the behavior you are describing? Can you give us the js output in the error case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're confused about how the AJAX is working.  It looks like you expect that the AJAX call can work with PHP located on the same page in a way that the page is loaded only once.  That's not accurate; what you need is another php page that is called on the server that returns the data as JSON to the original page.  You've also got an issue with your callback, as the data will not be ready before receiveAndPrint() is called; it needs to be called in the callback (but it will only be *print* at that point, since the receive part will already be done).

Let's say you have two PHP files, a.php and b.php.  The first will be used to display the initial page and will call the second to retrieve the new data for a particular instance of `parent`.

a.php

```
jQuery.noConflict();        

function printSubCategories(categories) {

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

        var opt = document.createElement('option');

        opt.text = categories[i]['name'];
        opt.value = categories[i]['id'];

        jQuery('#subcategories').append(opt);
    }    
}


function ajaxCategories(pathToFile, ajaxData) {  
    jQuery.get(pathToFile, {'parent' : ajaxData}, function(data) {
        printSubCategories(data);
    });
}
```

called as

```
ajaxCategories('/b.php','value_of_parent');
```

b.php

```
<?php
    $categories = getCategories(json_decode($_GET['parent']));
    header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
<?=json_encode($categories)?>
```

You might also want to make sure the response isn't cached.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store');
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a huge help. However, I'm at a point where I need to ensure that the data passed to the other form is able to get back to the original form it was passed from. How would I do this? Would I need to put an ajax javascript function in my b.php file which would somehow pass the encoded data back to a.php?

Comment: No, the second php file only delivers the data.  It will received as the `data` parameter in the callback function to the jQuery `get` function.  That's the part that runs on the client to accept the data from the second PHP file that is being called.